# how to use an interface to force a generic datatype from a template in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, interface

Good morning, I've already searched for a few things but can't get the answer. I'm creating a generic class, and the idea is that generic data tye (typename T) should come from an interface:

this is the interface:

```
template<typename T> class iDataType{

public:

   virtual bool writeOnFile(std::fstream& theFile,T& data) = 0;
   virtual T readOnFile(std::fstream& theFile) = 0;

};
```

And this is what I'm 'trying' to do:

```
template <typename T : public iDataType> class Database{};
```

**thank you for your time.**

Comment: can you use `C++20` ?

Comment: The problem may be simplified. But in this case, the base classes depend on the type and there is no common base above them -- so you don't get some common base, and the base classes don't implement anything -- so you don't get some common implementation, the base restriction is less useful than imposing the restriction that T has the member functions you want with the signatures you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The requirement that `T` derive from `iDataType<T>` in the limited context of the question does not seem to add value. But, to answer the question as I interpret it, the property you want to be true is:

```
std::is_convertible_v<T*, iDataType<T>*>
```

`std::is_base_of` is misleading in that it will answer whether `T` has a base of `iDataType<T>`, but the language requires a public unambiguous base for a `T&` to be used as an `iDataType<T>&`. So, in C++, when you want to know if something has a base class as an interface, `std::is_base_of` is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You can assert on compile-time condition with `static_assert`, and there is `std::is_base_of`.

So the solution is:

```
template <typename T> class Database{
   static_assert(std::is_base_of<iDataType<T>, T>::value, "should be derived from iDataType");
};
```

Note that the solution is for C++11, for later C++ Standard you can use `std::is_base_of_v` and terse `static_assert` (without string literal parameter).

Comment: `std::is_base_of` answers whether `T` inherits from `iDataType<T>`, but not whether a `T*` can be used as a `iDataType<T>*` (it does not answer whether it inherits publicly or unambiguously).